# Find the dimensions of a 2D array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm playing around with Arrays in Java and had this doubt. How do I find the dimensions of a 2D array in java? For example, I get an array input from System.in and pass it in another method like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int arr[][] = new int[6][6];
for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < 6; j++){
                arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
}
findSize(arr);
/*
*
*Other code
*
*/
findSize(int[] inputArr){
//I want to find the dimensions of the array here
}
```

Both dimensions of the array are greater than 0. Appreciate the help.

Comment: `arr.length` is the number of rows, and each row may have a different number of columns (`arr[0].length` is the number of columns for the first row). Finally, `findSize` takes an array with a single dimension.

Answer (score 6):

This method:

```
findSize(int[] inputArr){
//I want to find the dimensions of the array here
}
```

is getting as parameter a 2 dimentional array

hence you should do:

```
findSize(int[][] inputArr){
     int heiht = inputArr.length;
     int width = inputArr[0].length;
}
```

Comment: You may want to change long to length. long is a pre-defined key-word in Java

Comment: This is a useful method, really! Thanks!

Comment: This is a useful method, really! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just need to access the 0th element of the array like this:

```
int size = inputArr[0].length;
```

This would do the trick!

Comment: Note that each entry of `inputArr` could have a different length for jagged arrays.

Answer (score 2):

A 2-dimensional array is an array of arrays. To get the actual length of the second dimension (which can be different for each array entry of the first dimension) do this:

```
int[] findSize(int[][] inputArr) {
    int[] size = new int[inputArr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        size[i] = inputArr[i].length;
    }

    return size;
}
```

To get 2D-Array dimension 1:

```
int size_1 = inputArr.length;
```

To get 2D-Array dimension 2:

```
int[] size_2 = findSize(inputArr);
```